# iOS Local Notifications Testing

Tags: ios, datetime, testing, xamarin, uilocalnotification

In testing my local notifications, for some reason setting the date and time on my iOS device does not trigger my local notification to appear. My notification's fire date is set to be several days in the future. If I do wait a few days then I will see my local notification.

Why am I not seeing my local notification by setting the date and time on my device?

Below is a sample:

```
            playNotification.FireDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(71.67f);
            playNotification.AlertAction = "Alert text";
            playNotification.AlertBody = "Alert body";
            playNotification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;
            playNotification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(playNotification);
```

I should mention that I changed 'AddHours' to 'AddSeconds' and tested this by waiting the specified number of seconds, and the notifications fired as expected. But somehow changing the date and time on my device does not.

Comment: That is strange. I am using the same approach to test the local notifications and it works if I change the date on the device. Could you please provide us with some code?

Comment: Okay I have edited my question to add sample code.

Comment: what does `DateTime.Now.AddHours(71.67f)` return? anyways... try this `playNotification.FireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];` (_go to the home screen within 10secs to ensure that you are getting the local notification_)

Comment: I tried something similar which was to change 'AddHours' to 'AddSeconds', waited the specified number of seconds, and this fired my notifications as expected. The AddHours(71.67) returns a date time that is 3 days minus 20 minutes from now. I tested this and it did give me the expected value.

Comment: kindly NSLog `DateTime.Now.AddHours(71.67f)` and add that to the question because something with the `NSDate` may be amiss

Comment: I ran this today on a device that is set to March 21 at 12:12pm and my `Console.WriteLine` of the firing date returned the following (the March 24th entry is the one that will occur 71.67 hours from now):
`Fire at: 3/23/2014 11:51:59 AM`
`Fire at: 3/24/2014 11:51:59 AM`
`Fire at: 3/27/2014 11:51:59 AM`
`Fire at: 4/20/2014 11:51:59 AM`

Comment: so i guess you'll have to wait :-∫

Comment: The notifications `FireDate` is of type `NSDate` and you should specify the `DateTimeKind` when creating the `DateTime`. Like `this: notification.FireDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(year, month, day), DateTimeKind.Local);`. I had a similar problem once and I found out that without specifying the kind, the notifications were fired a few hours later. But the logs seems ok on your side so I am not sure about it.

Comment: Well my notifications are appearing after the specified number of days. But unfortunately still cannot test them by manually changing the date\time on the device.

Comment: Then I have no more suggestions. Sorry I could not help.

Comment: From my tinkering it appears that they will only fire if you cross the fireDate threshold organically.  That is, you have to sit and watch the device cross the fireDate.  If you set the system clock PAST the fireDate then iOS appears to simply ignore the notification.  Perhaps to prevent a barrage of outdated notifications when a user changes their clock.  Unfortunately this makes testing notifications in the far future a pain.  You have to set the system clock to just BEFORE the fireDate and then sit and wait.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `timeZone` of the notifications. By default, the `timeZone` is set according to your location so it does not affect if you manually change your date and time. To achieve this, you need to set the `timeZone` to `systemTimeZone()`.

Like this:

```
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

I know this is in swift, but I know very little objective-c. 
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with changing time zones.

Comment: Yes it does. I had encountered the same problem when testing my app and the notification would not fire when changing the time and date on my phone. After I changed the timezone from default to system, my notification would fire when manually setting the time on my phone. Please try and test the code and understand what I am trying to say before down voting.